# change numbers to strings in json dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{"first": {"phone": 1900,"other": 1}, "second": {"adwords": 1419, "no_om_source": 1223}}
```

I convert this dict into json format. I wanted to change all the numbers within the dict to be changes to strings as well.

```
 def convert(o):
        if isinstance(o, np.generic): return o.item()  
        raise TypeError

 jsonContent = json.dumps(myDict, default=convert)
    with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(jsonContent, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    return jsonContent
```

However, when I try to print the `jsonContent`, the values are still in numbers and not strings. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before turning your dict into a json format.

```
myDict = {"first": {"phone": 1900,"other": 1}, "second": {"adwords": 1419, "no_om_source": 1223}}
for x in myDict:
    for k,v in myDict[x].items():
        myDict[x][k] = str(v)
```

output

```
{'first': {'phone': '1900', 'other': '1'}, 'second': {'adwords': '1419', 'no_om_source': '1223'}}
```